# Convert excel table to text file

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple task to do but I have no idea about VBs. I have excel file structured like this:

```
ID  |  File name  |  Title
-------------------------------
 1  |    1.mim    | ABC Song
 2  |    2.mim    | Five little monkeys
 3  |    3.mim    | Counting bananas
```

I need to generate text output from excel file in the form below:

```
<li>
    <a href="#" onclick="window.plugins.videoPlayer.play('file:///storage/emulated/0/nepal/%id%.mim');">
        <img src="img/radiologo/%id%.jpg" alt="" />
        <div class="channel-info">
            <h1>%Title%</h1>
        </div>
    </a>
</li>
```

Could you help me out with this please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK resolved, here is code below

```
Sub main()
    Dim fs As Object, f As Object, i As Integer
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Call createFile(f, fs, "Z:\Tablets\output.html")
    i = 2
    While Cells(i, 1) <> ""
        Call writeTab(f, 2, "<li>")
        Call writeTab(f, 3, "<a href=""#"" onclick=""window.plugins.videoPlayer.play('file:///storage/emulated/0/nepal/" & Cells(i, 1) & ".mim');"">")
        Call writeTab(f, 4, "<img src=""img/icons/" & Cells(i, 1) & ".jpg"" alt=""""     />")
        Call writeTab(f, 4, "<div class=""channel-info"">")
        Call writeTab(f, 5, "<h1>" & Cells(i, 4) & "</h1>")
        Call writeTab(f, 4, "</div>")
        Call writeTab(f, 3, "</a>")
        Call writeTab(f, 2, "</li>")
        i = i + 1
    Wend
    Set f = Nothing: Set fs = Nothing
End Sub
Sub createFile(fileObject As Object, fso As Object, fileName As String, Optional utf16 As Integer = 0)

    Set fileObject = fso.opentextfile(fileName, 2, True, utf16)
End Sub

Sub writeTab(f As Object, ByVal t As Integer, ByVal s As String)

    Dim tabString As String, i As Integer
    For i = 1 To t
        tabString = tabString & Chr(9)
    Next i
    f.writeline tabString & s
End Sub
```